# How do I extract the last value from an Observable and return it?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm doing some more RxJava experiments, mostly trying to figure out design patterns that would work for my business. I created a simple flight tracking application that tracks multiple flights, and reacts accordingly when a flight moves.

Suppose I have a `Collection<Flight>` with `Flight` objects. Each flight has an `Observable<Point>` specifying the latest coordinate received of its location. How do I extract the latest `Flight` object itself from the observable without having to save it to a whole separate variable? Is there no `get()` method or something similar on the `Observable`? Or am I thinking too imperatively?

```
public final class Flight {

    private final int flightNumber;
    private final String startLocation;
    private final String finishLocation;
    private final Observable<Point> observableLocation;
    private volatile Point currentLocation = new Point(0,0); //prefer not to have this

    public Flight(int flightNumber, String startLocation, String finishLocation) {

        this.flightNumber = flightNumber;
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
        this.finishLocation = finishLocation;
        this.observableLocation = FlightLocationManager.get().flightLocationFeed()
                .filter(f -> f.getFlightNumber() == this.flightNumber)
                .sample(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .map(f -> f.getPoint());

        this.observableLocation.subscribe(l -> currentLocation = l);
    }
    public int getFlightNumber() { 
        return flightNumber;
    }
    public String getStartLocation() { 
        return startLocation;
    }
    public String getFinishLocation() { 
        return finishLocation;
    }
    public Observable<Point> getObservableLocation() { 
        return observableLocation.last();
    }
    public Point getCurrentLocation() { 
        return currentLocation; //returns the latest observable location
        //would like to operate directly on observable instead of a cached value
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, too imperative.  You should be passing the information to what ever needs it in your subscription.

Comment: I was concerned about that. I guess it defeats the purpose if you turn something observable into something non-observable.

Comment: If you are a purist, yes.  You might be more pragmatic. ;)

Comment: I have a feeling I might need to be the latter, especially with existing applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this, essentially by creating a [BlockingObservable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html). This is flaky though as it has the potential to hang if the underlying observable does not complete:

```
observableLocation.toBlocking().last()
```